# inserting logic into ansible variable

Tags: ansible, yaml, devops

very noob question, I have this piece of ansible code in /vars/myvars.yml:

```
service: "{{ 'service1' if litespeed|bool==true else 'service2' }}" 

services_node:
    - foo
    - bar
    - "{{ service }}"
    - baz
```

i have tried to look online for my answer but cannot find anything, what syntax is in the curly braces? Searching online results in "there is no *if/else* in ansible or YAML" in most cases. To what kind of query or language that syntax is from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ansible uses Jinja for templating. You should read [ansible templating doc](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_templating.html).
You'll also find a lot of useful informations on Jinja's [template designer doc](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/).

In your example, the syntax with the pipe (the `|` symbol) is the syntax for filters. [Here](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#list-of-builtin-filters) you'll find the list of builtin filters with documentation and examples.

You'll see that the bool filter is not listed as it is a filter brought by ansible. You'll find the list of these filters [here](https://ansible-docs.readthedocs.io/zh/stable-2.0/rst/playbooks_filters.html).

The template itself is not part of Yaml, that's why it is expressed as a string.

Answer (score 0):

The braces are part of a Jinja2 template within the YAML data. See [Templating (Jinja2)](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_templating.html) for complete information.